# How can I determine users that are NOT connecting using Cached Exchange Mode?

Tags: exchange

(without going round and checking each machine)

Is this possible?

Running Exchange Server 2003

Mixture of Outlook 2003 + 2007 clients.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure thing
Get-LogonStatistics “UserName” | FL Name, ClientName, ClientMode

mode = 0/1/2
0 = 'unknown' and seems to indicate pre-Outlook 2003 or some other clients like blackberry.
1 = Online mode
2 = Cached mode

Comment: The question was for Exchange 2003. This is an Exchange 2007 Powershell CmdLet.

Answer (score 3):

If your goal is to enforce or disable Cached Exchange Mode for everybody or a certain group of users, then you can use Group Policy with the Office (Outlook) 2003/2007 adm templates.

Answer (score 2):

[Enabling/Disabling Exchange Cached Mode through the regisry](http://www.howto-outlook.com/howto/cachedmoderegkey.htm).  You can remotely access machines registries to check once the user is logged in -- or write a slightly elaborate tool with PSTools to check to see if a user is logged into a given workstation, query the registry key, and create a list.  You could also make a [login script](http://episteme.arstechnica.com/eve/forums/a/tpc/f/6330927813/m/645004135831/inc/1) that would dump to a common drive when a user logs in, on what machine, and if caching is available.

If you have <20 machines it would probably be just a simple to check each machine via the regedit tool (with Admin privs on a domain) against each workstation.

Comment: Thanks.   Which registry entry would I check?

Answer (score 1):

If you're just looking to make a list of cached/uncached users, rather than disable cached mode in some way, A bit of intelligent scripting can help point the way. The thing is that uncached mode creates a persistent connection to the Exchange servers. So write a script that does a netstat every minute for a while and then post-analyze for the IP addresses that are on more than one consecutive netstat dump.

Alternately, if you're in a domain, the PSTOOLS set from SysInternals can help you build a script to check client-machine registry entries for the cached/uncached mode values. It's still visiting every machine, but in an automated way so you don't have to do it your self.

Comment: Thanks.   Which registry entry would I check?